# GLMER results reporting

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, glmm, post-hoc, reporting

I used a GLMM to fit a poisson distribution. The likelihood ratio test with the null model is significant, and now I should carry out a posthoc analysis. Using glht:multcomp I got this output:

```
                    Estimate   Std.Error zvalue 

> C - POST == 0    0.19402    0.03025    6.413     8.55e-10 *** 
> 
> E - POST == 0    0.19089    0.03927    4.861     5.83e-06 ***
```

How do I report these results? "0.19402" has a different scale from my raw values. I don't think reporting the raw means would make sense...